# Surge current capability of LFP batteries

Tags: batteries, solar-energy, surge-protection

LFP batteries, like all batteries, have a limited max current output. Unlike the grid, understood as a "giant battery," which can deal with an A/C compressor's demand of up to 2x of its rated continuous current max (e.g. as defined by the breaker size it's connected to) for some milliseconds, that short sub-second spike cannot be supplied by a battery.

Three questions:

1. Does a spike demand (up to the battery's max capability, obviously) potentially damage the battery long term, eg by diminishing its lifetime?
2. Why do some LFP battery suppliers specify much higher spike current capability (e.g. Franklin) while it's essentially the same chemistry as their competition?
3. Would a "soft start" (electronic "current spike remover") potentially help? Or might the AC compressor not even start rotating without that initial "current kick"?

Comment: What brings you to the conclusion the battery can’t supply a short term burst in current?  I can tell you that many of the Lithium cell technologies can supply well in excess of the rated nominal current for short terms without damage. It comes down to cell impedance and heating.

Answer (score 1):

The premise in your first sentence is wrong. The rest of the question is therefore moot.

All batteries will supply much more current than their rating if asked to, that is, if loaded by too heavy a load. That's why it's essential to use a fuse when the batteries used are types that can deliver a very high current.

It's the duration of that current surge that dictates what, if anything, is damaged by heating, either in the battery or the external circuit.

It's the voltage drop at the battery terminals, which we often say is due to the delivered current times the battery's internal resistance, which determines whether the load will still operate when drawing that current surge.

Given the chemistry and construction of the battery, the manufacturer sets the current rating at a level that the battery can supply continuously without damage to itself, and while meeting other specifications like run time.

Answer (score 1):

ALL actions damage a battery - charging discharging or just sitting there.  How much varies. The manufacturer factors these into the specification.

A transient load up to less than or equal the battery's rated short term maximum will damage the battery by a small amount such that the battery meets its overall manufacturers specification.

A manufacturer will often specify a normal maximum continuous current and a maximum short term overload, with a specified period. They will not usually say how often such overloads occur but the assumption is (probably) that they constitute a small part of the usage period.

IF you can limit peak current on starting "it will not do any harm" but as long as you meet battery specifications it's liable to be acceptable to connect the load directly.

Even loads in excess of absolute maximum rating MAY be acceptable, but you are then exploring territory that the manufacturer has not commented on, and any warranties are liable to be voided.